# Does assets/ folder reside in device's RAM?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

When I launch the app, where do the assets/ folder contents go?
Are they loaded into RAM?

Or maybe AssetsManager always reads from inside /sdcard/?

Am I safe to assume that any Android device handles assets/ folder in the same manner?

My concern comes from the fact that some devices that I target are very limited in the amount of RAM they can provide, while all of them have a decent /sdcard/ storage, therefore I must decide if the assets should be downloaded at runtime or if they can safely be included into the apk file.

Comment: whats the difference where is it mapped to? physical file or cached in the RAM?

Comment: @pskink made an edit

Comment: read about the limits here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully launched a 587 MB application on a device that comes with 512 MB available RAM, so it turns out that *at least* some of the devices indeed avoid pulling the whole assets/ folder to RAM upon launching the application.

Answer (score 1):

Assets are not saved in the "external files" directory (a.k.a the SD card). They're saved in the main app storage.

You can encourage your app to be installed on the SD card via [android:installLocation="preferExternal"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html). Your app will use this less valuable storage for everything, not just assets.

To have just assets on external storage consider [expansion files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) like @pskink mentioned in a comment, or downloading them yourself and caching them in external storage.